# How to modify Rollover image effect with HTML?

Tags: html

I have an image   with a "Visit" button on it that is image mapped with HTML code, it has a roll over effect so that when you put your mouse over the "visit" link, it shows a glow version of the visit button.

But right now the code is not correct, the rollover effect replaces the original image with the glow version image, I simply want the glow version to overlay the original version at the same exact coordinates that are in the html code below: `coords="52,63,145,100"`

I don't want it replace the whole image. And I want the glow version to maintain its normal size. This is the code so far:

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:200px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<img id="Image-Maps_3201304212133558" src="http://www.image-maps.com/uploaded_files/3201304212133558_example78.png" usemap="#Image-Maps_3201304212133558" border="0" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
<map id="_Image-Maps_3201304212133558" name="Image-Maps_3201304212133558">
<area shape="rect" coords="52,63,145,100" href="yahoo.com" alt="visit!" title="visit!" onMouseOver="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps_3201304212133558').src= 'http://s15.postimg.org/a71gazzzr/visit_glow.pngmage-maps.com/';" onMouseOut="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps_3201304212133558').src= 'http://www.image-maps.com/uploaded_files/3201304212133558_example78.png';"  />
<area shape="rect" coords="198,198,200,200" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_3201304212133558" alt="Image Map" title="Image Map" />
</map>

</div>
```

[Here is a live demo.](http://cssdesk.com/gj9WS)

Comment: Here is a live demo example of the issue: http://cssdesk.com/gj9WS    It shows what happens, try putting your mouse over the image

Answer (score 0):

You're literally replacing the image in the  tag, so you're not going ot be able to show two pictures simultaneously unless you load the base image into a separate element.

One option would be to change the : add `background-image: url(http://www.image-maps.com/uploaded_files/3201304212133558_example78.png);` to the style attribute. (and, for neatness, you could replace the base image in the  tag with a transparent png).

This isn't the right approach though, for a number of reasons. Images harm SEO, they are slower to load, some browsers have problems with png transparency, google translate won't translate them, etc, etc, etc.

Besides, you can do all this in css:
http://jsfiddle.net/as2003/AbVTK/

Comment: Ya id love to do it with css but I don't know anything about programing or making seperate files connect to each other, etc... I mean Id pay you to do it for me lol. But no way could I figure it out

Comment: MY entire website is one big jpeg image that is html image mapped for links. So is it possible to add css glow effects to a specific coordinate of the image, inline with HTML?  So Basically make a glow effect with CSS, and position it to exact coordinate on the image, inline to the HTML?

Comment: I guess so. remove the image map, and create a bunch of positioned <a> tags, with the box-shadow on a:hover?

Comment: But I need to keep the HTML image map, that's how the links work for the image. I just want to add CSS glow inline with the HTML. I just don't know what the code would look like....                    div.outer {
    background-color: #008;
    padding: 4em;
}

div.outer a {
    background-color: #080;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
}

div.outer a:hover {
    background-color: #0f0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #fff;
}    applied to coords="52,63,145,100"

Comment: like the CSS glow hover over effect is easy, just a couple code lines, But I don't know how to implement and combine it with those coordinates, and inline with the html provided in my question at top

Comment: You can't use pseudo classes (e.g. `:hover`) in inline css. This might help you: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/imap - I'd just like the reiterate that this is not the right way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this what you're looking for by removing this code all together and creating the both the button and the glow-hover effect with CSS.

The issue with your current code is that that method of rollover effect, ie image replacement via mapping, is very cumbersome and out-of-fashion, so to speak.

The web is literally covered in resources in regards to CSS and even HTML, and I would suggest looking into them.

For your query in particular, check this out: http://designshack.net/articles/css/four-simple-and-fun-css-button-hover-effects-for-beginners/

Comment: Well then what about instead of using the image for a roll over effect, is there a way to use CSS to make a glow effect at those EXACT coordinates? so that way when people put their mouse over that part of the image, a css glow appears? is that possible? The thing is my site is html, so I would need to put the css code inline with html

Comment: The thing is you shouldn't be dealing with coordinates, but I just saw you comment on another answer that you've built the whole site from a giant image and adding maps on it. For future reference, do not build / code a site like this. I mean, you could have a glow effect appear when the button image is hovered, but only if the button were a separate image itself (but again, you've made the whole site one image).

Comment: "The thing is you shouldn't be dealing with coordinates, "   ...so even though I shouldn't because I know it is a terrible way to make a site, it is possible though?

Comment: If you refer back to Aidan's original answer, no. The way you have the code set is that the image with the glow effect completely replaces the original image, not layer the new image on top of the old one. That's why you're also getting the resizing issue, as the new image is trying to trade out with the original image and fill out the whole space that has been defined (width="400", height="400"). If you really want to achieve what you want without having to rebuild the site, make the hover image the same size and appearance as the original image, but add the glow to the button there.

Comment: First image: http://i.imgur.com/nI7kIfh.png
Second (hover) image: http://i.imgur.com/xXnS7It.png

Comment: Eh that would not work because my actual website is a huge jpeg image, so it would be switching back and forth between two huge images. Im sure there is a way to inline the CSS effect to specific coordinates on an image, I just have to find out how

Answer (score 0):

i am going to do my best here to convince you to rethink what you're doing.  I know you want an answer to your question but the truth is, I dont think theres a way to do it.  The problem is the original image is one thing and the rollover button is another thing.  When this was the norm you had to create the original button and rollover button to be exactly the same size, and dpi in order for it to work and look right.  If you wanted to have something in the middle of the image you had to slice out the part you wanted to change and use css and divs or (God Forbid) a table, to make it work.

In the year 2013, you can accomplish everything you're looking to do with CSS3 and NO images at all.

this site will make them for you and just give you the code when you're done.
http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/

this one used images incase you wanted something a little more special than what text can provide,

http://designshack.net/articles/css/four-simple-and-fun-css-button-hover-effects-for-beginners/

Good luck

**EDIT:**  I am sleepy so when I was telling you what was wrong with your original stuff I dont think I did a good job.  The original image is a huge thing with a border and a small button in the middle.  The hover button is just the small button.  You're thinking you can using a hover effect to replace just the small button in the middle with the overlay image.  This might be possible with javascript but I am not really sure you can do this with a hover effect.  If this is possible its not a good way to do it.

Comment: but my site is an entire giant image, that is image mapped with html code. Because I don't know programming. That's why I was trying to do this so it would work with my image, css wouldn't work unless I rebuilt my whole website out of css. Right now my entire site is one big jpeg image that is linked mapped with html.

Comment: hmm, I would like to help you but I just don think its possible to do what you want without programming.  Back in the day (a long time ago) i used to use Photoshop to take my sites 1 big image and slice it into smaller chunks so that I could do things similar to what you're doing.  Its an old school approach that would still work but would require you to get your hands on a copy of photoshop.  Look up a feature called slicing and see if that helps.  Good luck to you.